# How to set permissions so users can add, edit, and delete list/lib items, but cannot edit web part pages or delete web part pages? (SharePoint)

Tags: sharepoint

I need the ability for users to add, edit, and delete lists/libraries but not have the ability to edit web part pages or delete web part pages. I am boggled that the Edit Items permission allows for editing and deleting web part pages. The alternative I see at the moment is setting Read permissions across the entire site, and then setting specific permissions on each individual List/Library. The problem with this is that I have site templates, so the security does not remain in the site template (it inherits from the parent). Can someone clarify this for me? Or suggest what permission level I should use to accomplish my goal stated above? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue at a client site.  The workaround I found that worked out rather well was to break the permissions on the 'Pages' document library and set that to read only (with the exception of the groups that actually needed rights to edit pages).

HTH

-CK

Comment: Sometimes the simplest things in life are the hardest to figure out. Thanks.

Comment: Anytime, best of luck to you.